# Problems using phpmailer 5.2 version

Tags: php, html

so I building my own web trying to create an email verification by using phpmailer 5.2 version in github.
My code is currect but I don't get any mails (there is no errors there)
I will be glad if someone can help me with that

```html
  <?php

  $conn= new mysqli('localhost','root','','up');
mysqli_query($conn,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");





if($conn->connect_error){

exit('Cannot connect');

}
else{
  $button='';
if((isset($_POST["username"]))||(isset($_POST["fullname"]))||(isset($_POST["password"]))||(isset($_POST["email"]))||(isset($_POST["gender"]))||(isset($_POST["vkey"]))){
$username=$_POST['username'];
$fullname=$_POST['fullname'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$gender= $_POST['gender'];
$vkey=md5(time().$username);//verification code always changes according to the compuechos time zone
$password=md5($password);
     $sql="INSERT INTO signup (Username,Fullname,Password,Email,Gender,`Vkey`) VALUES ('$username','$fullname','$password','$email','$gender','$vkey')";

 if($conn->query($sql)){

require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$mail= new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->PHPAuth= true;
$mail->SMTPSecure='tls';
$mail->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port=25;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Username='my email';
$mail->Password='my pass';
$mail->SetFrom=('my email');
$mail->Subject='hello';
$mail->Body='hello';
$mail->Send();
 echo "<script>alert('משתמש נוצר בהצלחה נא לגשת לתיבת המייל לצורך אימות')</script>";
 }

}

}

?>
```

Comment: How do you monitor errors?

Comment: There are many duplicates here on SO along this topic.  You can turn on helpful debugging information in PhpMailer that may help you trace issues.

Comment: Hey  thank you for the rapid answers I tried to check for mistakes by using $mail= new PHPMailer(true); errors did not pop up while running

Comment: you might need to check that email config. use a smtp testing service like mailtrap.io to test your mails and then switch over to your gmail.

Comment: Maybe I need to change some of  the settings in php.ini file?

Comment: Before you change any settings.  Read about debugging Phpmailer.  Start with a very simple script that just fires a simple email.  https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging and https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Those links above are likely for the latest version.  Check the SMTP examples on the 5.2 branch. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/5.2-stable/examples